# How to insert hardcoded data into database

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I try to put harcoded data in my "FeedReader.db" but I don't know how it works. It shows me something like this :
[image: Database]

How can I insert data using Android Studio but without aditional buttons (just using constant variables in code). This is important for me because I need to see how is data inserted in db. The XML file doesn't contain anything because for the moment I want only to see SQLite and Android studio connectivity.

```
   UserModel

    package com.example.password

class UserModel(val websiteid: String, val websitename: String, val userid: String, val password: String, val salt: String)
```

DBContract

```
    package com.example.password

import android.provider.BaseColumns

object DBContract {

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    class UserEntry : BaseColumns {
        companion object {
            val TABLE_NAME = "users"
            val COLUMN_WEBSITE_ID = "websiteid"
            val COLUMN_WEBSITE_NAME = "websitename"
            val COLUMN_USER_ID = "userid"
            val COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password"
            val COLUMN_SALT = "salt"
        }
    }
}
```

UserDBHelper

```
    package com.example.password

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class UsersDBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }


    companion object {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        val DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db"

        private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_WEBSITE_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_WEBSITE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " TEXT, " +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_SALT + " TEXT)"

        private val SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.password


import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var usersDBHelper : UsersDBHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1)

        usersDBHelper = UsersDBHelper(this)
    }


}
```

Comment: you should consider using Room, it makes database operations much easier

Comment: I need to use AES algorithm in the future, I don't know if it's possible to do this if I use Room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function to your `UsersDBHelper` class which inserts some dummy data into database.

```
fun addDummyData() {
    val db = writableDatabase
    db.beginTransaction()
    try {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE_ID, "WEB-007")
        values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE_NAME, "MY_WEB")
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_ID, "User-1")
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, "******")
        values.put(COLUMN_SALT, "1234")

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
        db.setTransactionSuccessful()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("SQLITE", "Error while inserting data")
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction()
    }
}
```

Now simply call this from your `Activity` as

```
usersDBHelper.addDummyData()
```

Comment: I need to call it from MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes add the above line after `usersDBHelper = UsersDBHelper(this)` in Activity onCreate